# Binding with filter not updating

Tags: angularjs

I'm updating a value on `$scope` in a callback from a service. The callback executes but the update to the binding is not reflected in the view.

Controller:

```
$scope.changeStartDateOk = function(){
  UserService.changeStartDate($scope.startDateSelected.value, function(){
    $scope.startDate = $scope.startDateSelected.value;
    console.log('callback called');
  });
};
```

View:

```
<div><p class="left">Start date</p><p class="right">{{startDate | formatDateLong}}</p><div style="clear: both;"></div></div>
```

I've tried `$scope.$digest()` and `$scope.apply()` to no avail. Is this being caused by the presence of the filter on the view?

Filter:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('formatDateLong', function() {
return function(input) {
  var date = new Date(input);

  if(isNaN(date.getTime())) {
    return 'N/A';
  }

  return date.getDate() + '-' +
    ['January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'][date.getMonth()] + '-' +
    date.getFullYear();
};
```

Comment: Can you build a Plunker or something showing it not working? It's difficult to discern the problem from the posted code.

Comment: You need to provide the code of the `UserService` - it does not matter if the callback function is called - it should be called in the digest cycle.